# Include template as verbatim

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template which I'm inserting with include tag:

```
{% include 'template.html' %}
```

Also in another place I want its contents to be displayed as raw. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

page1.html

```
{%with flag="norender" %}
    {% include "template.html" %}
{%endwith%}
```

template.html

```
{%if flag == "norender" %}
    {%verbatim%}
{%endif%}
        {#your html #}
{%if flag == "norender" %}
    {%endverbatim%}
{%endif%}
```

Comment: Does this work? Isn't `{%endif%}` below the first verbatim, dangling without the `if` counter-part?

Comment: I get {%endif%}  my stuf....{%if flag == "norender" %} being displayed as you suggest.   This looks like a possible approach but template tag cannot be lifted directly, https://github.com/jrief/django-angular/blob/master/docs/template-sharing.rst

Comment: Unfortunately, as eugene says, this answer isn't correct. The django tags between `{% verbatim %}` and `{% endverbatim %}` are rendered, er, verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a template tag to do this:

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.utils.html import escape

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag()
def verbatim_include(name):
    """
    Example: {% verbatim_include "weblog/post.html" %}
    """
    template = get_template(name)
    return escape(template.render())
```

I've no idea if it's the best or most efficient method, but it seems to work OK for me (Django 1.11).

In my main template I'll include another like this:

```
<pre><code>{% verbatim_include 'my_template.html' %}</code></pre>
```

And if `my_template.html` is like this:

```
<b>This is my template</b>
```

Then in the browser I'll see:

```
<b>This is my template</b>
```

And not:

**This is my template**

Comment: I had to get rid of `escape()` but otherwise seems to work great. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting! I definitely need the `escape()` (Django 2.1 now).

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Django 1.11:

```py
from django import template
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def verbatim_include(name):
    """
    Example: {% verbatim_include "weblog/post.html" %}
    """
    template = get_template(name)
    source = template.template.source
    return mark_safe(source)
```